# Why does reduction from vertex cover to subset sum use base-4?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, proof-techniques

Why does reduction from vertex cover to subset sum use base-4?

[30.13 Subset Sum (from Vertex Cover)](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/30-nphard.pdf)

Comment: Please include the necessary background to your question in your question; this would help people find your question, and will also ensure it is relevant in case the web site you link to goes offline.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Do you understand how that existing reduction works?  Have you tried working through a variant of the reduction using some other base, to see if the reduction still goes through or if any of the steps no longer follows?  The obvious first step is to try reproducing the argument that the reduction is correct using some other base, and see what happens.  (I suspect you'll find that the carry bits screw things up, if you were to use base 2, but that any other base would be fine.)

Comment: I did these things but all the notes on the internet I looked at used base-4 so thought I was missing something. Sorry! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact base used is somewhat arbitrary. Since each "digit" could be as big as $2$, then you need to use base $b \geq 3$. Jeff probably chose $b = 4$ since it is the smallest power of $2$ which is at least $3$. Assuming your tape alphabet is binary, it is marginally simpler to handle bases which are powers of $2$. He might have well have chosen any (fixed) base $b \geq 3$, or even allow the base to very mildly with $n$.